# poner condición antes de insertar un registro

Tags: php, pdo

saludos amigo tengo una duda con respecto quisiera agregar una condición a mi código que antes de insertar un registro me diga lo siguientes: porque el mínimo de registros a seleccionar es 3 y el máximo es 5, ejemplo si selecciono 2 registros o 6 registros debe indicar el mjs indicando que no cumple con el permitido el código funciona perfectamente pero lo que me faltaría es agregar solamente eso: seria algo como: **disculpe para registrar un proyecto deben haber mínimo 3 y un máximo de 5 alumnos**

**anexo el codigo**

```
 <!-- proceso para registrar-->
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

   $sql = "SELECT titulo_proyecto FROM inscripcion_proyectos WHERE 
   titulo_proyecto = :titulo_proyecto LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
   $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
   $check->bindParam(':titulo_proyecto', $_POST['titulo_proyecto']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
   $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
   $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
   if ($contador > 0) {
   $check->closeCursor();


    echo "<script>
         swal({
               title: 'Ups Aviso...',
               text: '¡ El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !',
               type: 'info',
               showConfirmButton: false, 
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false,
              allowEnterKey: false,
              });
         </script>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=5;URL=http:inscripcion.php>";

    }
    else
    {

   $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO inscripcion_proyectos (titulo_proyecto,id_pnf,id_profesor,idusuarios) VALUES (:titulo_proyecto,:id_pnf,:id_profesor,:idusuarios)");
   $sql->bindParam(':titulo_proyecto', $_POST['titulo_proyecto']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_pnf', $_POST['id_pnf']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_profesor', $_POST['id_profesor']);
   $sql->bindParam(':idusuarios', $_POST['idusuarios']);
   $sql->execute();
   $last_id = $DB_con->lastInsertId();



        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cedula']); $i++) {

   $sql2=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO inscripcion_alumnos 
   (idinscripcion_proyectos,cedula) VALUES 
   (:idinscripcion_proyectos, :cedula)");
   $sql2->bindParam(':idinscripcion_proyectos', $last_id);
   $sql2->bindParam(':cedula', $_POST['cedula'][$i]);
   $sql2->execute();


      echo "<script>
         swal({
               title: 'Bien Hecho...',
               text: '¡Registro Insertado Correctamente !',
               type: 'info',
               showConfirmButton: false, 
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false,
              allowEnterKey: false,
              });
            </script>
            <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=5;URL=http:inscripcion.php>";


               } 

              }
             }
       ?>
   <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

Answer (score 0):

pude resolverlos gracias anexo el código par quien pueda necesitarlo

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

$sql = "SELECT titulo_proyecto FROM inscripcion_proyectos WHERE 
titulo_proyecto = :titulo_proyecto LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
$check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera 
evitamos SQL Injection
$check->bindParam(':titulo_proyecto', 
$_POST['titulo_proyecto']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
$check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
$contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de 
resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
if ($contador > 0) {
$check->closeCursor();


    echo "<script>
         swal({
               title: 'Ups Aviso...',
               text: '¡ El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !',
               type: 'info',
               showConfirmButton: false, 
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false,
              allowEnterKey: false,
              });
         </script>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=5;URL=http:inscripcion.php>";



}

else

{

if(count($_POST['cedula']) > 2 && count($_POST['cedula']) < 6) { 

$sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO inscripcion_proyectos 
(titulo_proyecto,idcarreras,id_profesor,idusuarios) VALUES 
(:titulo_proyecto,:idcarreras,:id_profesor,:idusuarios)");
$sql->bindParam(':titulo_proyecto', $_POST['titulo_proyecto']);
$sql->bindParam(':idcarreras', $_POST['idcarreras']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_profesor', $_POST['id_profesor']);
$sql->bindParam(':idusuarios', $_POST['idusuarios']);
$sql->execute();
$last_id = $DB_con->lastInsertId();



        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cedula']); $i++) {

$sql2=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO inscripcion_alumnos 
(idinscripcion_proyectos,cedula) VALUES 
(:idinscripcion_proyectos, :cedula)");
$sql2->bindParam(':idinscripcion_proyectos', $last_id);
$sql2->bindParam(':cedula', $_POST['cedula'][$i]);
$sql2->execute();


      echo "<script>
         swal({
               title: 'Bien Hecho...',
               text: '¡Registro Insertado Correctamente !',
               type: 'info',
               showConfirmButton: false, 
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false,
              allowEnterKey: false,
              });
            </script>
            <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=5;URL=http:inscripcion.php>";


               } 

     } else { 

  echo "<script>
         swal({
               title: 'Ups Aviso...',
               text: '¡ El minimo de alumnos debe ser 3 y el maximo 5 por proyectos !',
               type: 'info',
               showConfirmButton: false, 
               allowOutsideClick: false,
               allowEscapeKey: false,
              allowEnterKey: false,
              });
         </script>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=5;URL=http:inscripcion.php>";

           } 

    }
}
?>
<!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```